# Getting db2 admin cfg

Tags: db2, admin

How can i get information, which shows by the command:
db2 get admin cfg
in other way - selecting from some table or reading some file.

Comment: db2 version? platform it's running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no IBM-supplied table function/view that will provide you with the DB2 administration server configuration (i.e. what you get from GET ADMIN CFG).  Furthermore, IBM does not even provide a public API to get this information.

Please note that the DB2 administration server is deprecated as of DB2 9.7.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on DB2 LUW, you may be able to find what you're looking for in the system configuration views  ([here is a link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022029.html) to the 9.7 publib page for one of the views, you can see the others in the same category on the left side menu) :

```
SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG
SYSIBMADM.DBCFG
SYSIBMADM.REG_VARIABLES
```

Try `SELECT * FROM table_name`

It definitely won't be formatted as nicely as the `db2 GET ADMIN CONFIG` command, but it should get you started.